# Python - How to break while loop after empty value in a int turning input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I want to make the while loop break when empty input is typed.
I know that the error is due to the int function because it cant turn to integer an empty input but how can i do what i'm trying to write?

```
while True:
    numb = int(input("number"))
    if numb % 2 == 0:
        print("this number is even")
    elif numb % 2 != 0:
        print("this number is odd")
    elif numb == '':
        break
```

Comment: you don't even need that last condition, an empty input would trigger a ValueError!

Comment: what if you changed that to `int(input("number") or '0 or sys.maxint')` and in your elif you break the loop if `numb` equals to that?

Comment: i want it to stop by putting an empty value without causing an error

Comment: @fips - If the input string is non-empty, it'll be sent to `int()`. If it is empty, the string `'0 or sys.maxint'` will be sent to `int()` instead, which isn't any more valid than an empty string for this purpose, and will produce the exact same behavior.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I meant to choose one of the two that may make more sense in this case, `0` or `sys.maxint` inside the string as a fallback, it seems to be working with `raw_input` in python 2 and `input` in python 3. e.g.: `int(input('number') or '0')` numb is set to 0 if user just hits enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
while True:
    try:
        numb = int(input("number"))
    except ValueError:
        break
    if numb % 2 == 0:
        print("this number is even")
    elif numb % 2 != 0:
        print("this number is odd")
```

Just handle the exception if the input cannot be converted into an integer.
Now, any input that is not an integer would terminate the loop.

Comment: I think using a try block is a good solution, but here an empty input returns a  SyntaxError and not a ValueError (while another string raises a NameError.

Comment: `int('')` and `int('a')` both give me `ValueError`. A SyntaxError would not allow the program to run in the first place.

Comment: I thought so too... However, I pasted your code in a file and when I run it I get this:
number3

this number is odd

number2

this number is even

number

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "sp.py", line 3, in <module>

    numb = int(input("number"))

  File "<string>", line 0

    

    ^

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Please use Python 3. :)

Comment: Great! You're right! :) However I didn't think it possible (even in Python 2) to get a SyntaxError from a user input...

Comment: `input()` in Python 2 uses `eval()` on the inputted string. So the user at the prompt actually types Python source code. This is the reason why it was changed in Python 3.

Comment: `input` on Python 2 evaluates the inputted data. That's the reason why noone with a sane mind ever uses `input` but `raw_input`on Python 2. [`eval`is dangerous!](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: OK. Thank your for the information :)